# Pattern matching on variant without deconstructing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

In the following code, the function `disp` is defined by de-constructing `Sum b c` and then immediately reconstructing it. The problem is that I don't need `b` and `c`, only the fact that it is of type `Sum`.

```
data Expr = Name String | Sum Expr Expr
    deriving(Show)

disp (Sum (Name a) (Sum b c)) = a ++ ":" ++ disp (Sum b c)
```

Is there a way of writing `disp` without this deconstruction - reconstruction (and the `b` and `c` bindings), or is this the correct way of writing such a function?

Comment: If you don't use the fact it's a `Sum` why  do you need to know it ? You probably just do  `disp (Sum (Name a) b`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`disp (Sum (Name a) s@(Sum _ _)) = a ++ ":" ++ disp s`

`@` allows multiple matches for the same thing

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'm learning Haskell and just curious: does something like `disp (Sum (Name a) s::Sum) = ...` exist? Then I wouldn't even have to use `_` or know the number of args to the Sum constructor.

Comment: if you add a function `isSum :: Expr -> Bool`, you can do `disp (Sum (Name a) s) | isSum s = a ++ ":" ++ disp s`

Comment: You can use `s@Sum{}` if you want to match without knowing the number of constructor arguments.